# Script on IE8 is not working

Tags: internet-explorer, fancybox

I'm creating a website fr my client but I'm having some problem with a script (fancybox with cloud-zoom) in IE. When I view my site in any other browser than IE everything works fine, but when a view it using IE 8 (most popular version) the script doesn't work right.

The link for the page where the script is: http://enzomodas.com.br/detalhe.php?id=149&tipo=15

What should I do?

Here goes the script code:

```
        $(function() {
            /*
            fancybox init on each cloud-zoom element
             */
            $("#content .cloud-zoom").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
                'transitionOut' :   'none',
                'speedIn'       :   600,
                'speedOut'      :   200,
                'overlayShow'   :   true,
                'overlayColor'  :   '#000',
                'cyclic'        :   true,
                'easingIn'      :   'easeInOutExpo'
            });

            /*
            because the cloud zoom plugin draws a mousetrap
            div on top of the image, the fancybox click needs
            to be changed. What we do here is to trigger the click
            the fancybox expects, when we click the mousetrap div.
            We know the mousetrap div is inserted after
            the <a> we want to click:
             */
            $("#content .mousetrap").live('click',function(){
                $(this).prev().trigger('click');
            });

            /*
            the content element;
            each list item / group with several images
             */
            var $content    = $('#content'),
            $thumb_list = $content.find('.thumb > ul');
            /*
            we need to set the width of each ul (sum of the children width);
            we are also defining the click events on the right and left arrows
            of each item.
             */
            $thumb_list.each(function(){
                var $this_list  = $(this),
                total_w     = 0,
                loaded      = 0,
                //preload all the images first
                $images     = $this_list.find('img'),
                total_images= $images.length;
                $images.each(function(){
                    var $img    = $(this);
                    $('<img/>').load(function(){
                        ++loaded;
                        if (loaded == total_images){
                            $this_list.data('current',0).children().each(function(){
                                total_w += $(this).width();
                            });
                            $this_list.css('width', total_w + 'px');

                            //next / prev events

                            $this_list.parent()
                            .siblings('.next')
                            .bind('click',function(e){
                                var current = $this_list.data('current');
                                if(current == $this_list.children().length -1) return false;
                                var next    = ++current,
                                ml      = -next * $this_list.children(':first').width();

                                $this_list.data('current',next)
                                .stop()
                                .animate({
                                    'marginLeft'    : ml + 'px'
                                },400);
                                e.preventDefault();
                            })
                            .end()
                            .siblings('.prev')
                            .bind('click',function(e){
                                var current = $this_list.data('current');
                                if(current == 0) return false;
                                var prev    = --current,
                                ml      = -prev * $this_list.children(':first').width();

                                $this_list.data('current',prev)
                                .stop()
                                .animate({
                                    'marginLeft'    : ml + 'px'
                                },400);
                                e.preventDefault();
                            });
                        }
                    }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing parentheses here:

```
$thumb_list = $content.find('.thumb > ul');
```